# Problema al cambiar una palabra de tipo string por otra palabra en una frase

Tags: java, string

Hola solo necesito ayuda al imprimir la frase ya cambiada porfavor. Al imprimir me sale lo siguiente: **[Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55**

Aquí esta mi código:

```
public static void main(String[]  args) throws IOException  {
        BufferedReader leer= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Hola ingresa una frase");
        String frase= leer.readLine();
        System.out.println("Ahora ingresa la palabra a suplir");
        String palabrai=leer.readLine();
        System.out.println("Finalmente ingresa por cual palabra necesitas cambiar");
        String sustituir=leer.readLine();
        String[] arreglofrase=frase.split(" ");
        String vacio="";
        for(int x=0;x<arreglofrase.length;x++){
            if (arreglofrase[x].equals(palabrai))
            {
                arreglofrase[x]=sustituir;
                System.out.println(arreglofrase.toString());
            }
        }


        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Estas imprimiendo todo el valor del arreglo :

```
System.out.println(arreglofrase.toString());
```

por eso obtienes:

```
Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55
```

Para imprimir el resultado con la palabra a sustituir, que imagino es lo que en realidad deseas hacer, podrías hacerlo después del `for` imprimiendo cada uno de los elementos del array, conteniendo el elemento con la palabra a reemplazar mediante:

```
  for (String s : arreglofrase) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
```

o si usas Java versión >= 8:

```
System.out.println(String.join(" ", arreglofrase));
```

por ejemplo:

```
        BufferedReader leer= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Hola ingresa una frase:");
    String frase= leer.readLine();
    System.out.println("Ahora ingresa la palabra a suplir:");
    String palabrai=leer.readLine();
    System.out.println("Finalmente ingresa por cual palabra necesitas cambiar:");
    String sustituir=leer.readLine();
    String[] arreglofrase=frase.split(" ");
    String vacio="";
    for(int x=0;x<arreglofrase.length;x++){
        if (arreglofrase[x].equals(palabrai))
        {
            arreglofrase[x]=sustituir;
           // System.out.println(arreglofrase[x].toString());
        }
    }

   for (String s : arreglofrase) {
        System.out.print(s + " ");
    }
```

esta sería un ejemplo de la salida:

```
Hola ingresa una frase:
Hola Cristian Castillo
Ahora ingresa la palabra a suplir:
Castillo
Finalmente ingresa por cual palabra necesitas cambiar:
Programador
Hola Cristian Programador
```

Comment: No sé por qué el negativo cuando esta es la única respuesta que explica el problema y soluciones usando Java 8 y pre Java 8

Answer (score 2):

Si estás utilizando Java 8, puedes usar el método [**`join`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) de la clase [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). El primer argumento es el *separador*, luego un *arreglo de cadenas*. Es decir:

```
for (int x = 0; x < arreglofrase.length; x++) {
    if (arreglofrase[x].equals(palabrai)) {
        arreglofrase[x] = sustituir;
    }
}

System.out.println(String.join(" ", arreglofrase));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me solucionaron ese problema!! :D

Comment: @CristianCastillo deberías marcar la respuesta que consideres mejor como correcta, si efectivamente resolvieron tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Como se ha mencionado el comportamiento que usted esta obteniendo es debido al uso de `arreglofrase.toString()`.

Para saber que sucede cuando usted llama a toString en este caso, puede mirar este [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

Dice algo asi:

> Devuelve una representación de string del objeto. En general, el
>   toString método devuelve una string que "representa textualmente" este
>   objeto. El resultado debe ser una representación conciso pero
>   informativo que es fácil para una persona a leer. **Se recomienda que
>   todas las subclases reemplazar este método**. El toString método para la
>   clase Object devuelve una cadena que consiste en el nombre de la clase
>   de la cual el objeto es una instancia, el carácter arroba ` @ ', y la
>   representación hexadecimal sin signo del código hash del objeto. En
>   otras palabras, este método devuelve una cadena igual al valor de:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

---

, caso a parte:

"usted podria sobrescribir este metodo, si tuviera un objeto el cual quiera que al usar ese metodo imprimiera algo en particular, solo lo menciono como nota"

---

Las soluciones anteriores son buenas, pero tambien podria usar algo asi es mas rustico pero funciona:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arreglofrase).replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\s", "")
                                                .replaceAll("\\,", " "));
```

### <kbd>[ideone Test](http://ideone.com/jrtPGd)</kbd>

Es compatible hacia a tras por poner algun ejemplo:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

```
arreglofrase
```

> es un objeto cuando haces el toString sin rescribir la funcion te
>   arroja generalmente el valor de memoria interna , para evitar eso
>   muestralo como un vector String

```
    for(String x:arregloFrase)
   {
System.out.println(x);
   }
```

> Con eso ya podras ver que resultado esta arrojando y empezar a corregir